# Can someone advise an efficient method of updating a list from another, based on matching properties from those lists?

Tags: c#, loops

I am attempting to update one list from another, based on properties within those lists, and whilst it is working, the results are extremely slow.

Consider this class:

```
Class A 
{
  int? Id { get; set; }
  string X { get; set; }
  string Y { get; set; }
  // this is followed by a dozen other properties, however, 
  // they are not relevant for this illustration
}
```

and the following class that I want to match against:

```
class B
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string X { get; set; }
  string Y { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of the two:

```
List<A> primaryList = new List<A>();
List<B> listToMatchAgainst = new List<B>();
```

Now, I want to update the Id from the items from list A with the ones from List B, where the respective X & Y values match.

The code I have is this:

```
foreach (var a in primaryList)
{
  var match = listToMatchAgainst.FirstOrDefault(b => b.X == a.X && b.Y == a.Y);
  if (match != null)
  {
    a.Id = match.Id;
  }
}
```

This works. The primary ids get updated with the matching ids from the list to get matched against. However, it's extraordinarily slow. If I do this operation where the two lists have several thousand items each, it takes 20 to 30 seconds.

I assume this is because underneath the hood it is doing nested loops.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of doing this? (likely by way of some sort of set based lambda expression).

Many thanks all.

Comment: Is it possible to use a dictionary for `listToMatchAgainst`? For example: `Dictionary<(string x, string y), B>`?

Comment: That is a fantast suggestion - I have just tried it and it considerably speeds up the process. Thank you very much

Comment: Also if you want to improve your lists performance look at this video with benchmarks about lists : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUZ3VKFyB-A

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ProgrammingLlama, moving to a dictionary-based model has tremendously improved the performance.

Many thanks